# Кроме людей(,) можно увидеть горы, леса... Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, дополнение

По Розенталю, обычно не обособляется оборот с предлогом кроме со значением включения в предложениях типа: Кроме зарплаты они получают премиальные.

- Тот ли это случай? Чуть выше приводится у Розенталя такой пример: "Кроме блюд и соусников, на столе стояло множество горшочков".

Answer (score 2):

**Кроме людей**, можно увидеть горы, леса (значение включения).

Обособлению оборота способствует структура предложения:

Сравнить: **Кроме людей**  изображены  живОтные: зАяц, олЕнь (значение включения).

Оборот вписывается в первую часть предложения.

**Пояснение**

Принято разделять обороты с союзом КРОМЕ **на две группы**: со значением исключения (всегда обособляется) и со значением включения (факультативное обособление).

На практике **обороты почти всегда обособляются**, так как плохо вписываются в структуру простого предложения.

С другой стороны, **оборот со значением исключения  может не обособляться**, если структура предложения позволяет это сделать.

**Примеры**

Потом, служа в суде, я **кроме столоначальства** никакой не вижу впереди карьеры. [Г. И. Успенский. Федор Михайлович Решетников (1874)] (исключение).

Я **кроме как уменьшать фотки и еще пару мелочей** ничего не умею (исключение).

Я **кроме военных** общался еще с техническими специалистами (включение)